# check if 2 vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ = $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to make sure that a system of any 2 vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ can make a lineair combination to $\Bbb R^2$.

The way I want to investigate is to row-reduce the matrix to enchelon form. This way I can check for consistentcy and see if the set has a single solution. Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare coordinates one by one. When you find a coordinate that is not zero in both vectors, you can divide them to find out what the scalar factor that takes one to the other must be if it exists at all. Check whether this factor works for the remaining coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are mathematically sound. However, in practice, you might want to avoid squaring and/or various summations (which may introduce serious canceling errors).

If your vectors are

$$x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}, \quad y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix},$$

and we assume $x,y \ne 0$ (otherwise, i.e., if one is zero, then it is a multiple of the other one), then define

$$k := \min \{ i \colon x_i \ne 0 \},$$

i.e., $k$ is the index of the first non-zero element in $x$. Now define $c := y_k / x_k$ and check that

$$y_i = c x_i \quad \text{for all $i=1,2,\dots,n$}.$$

If this is true, then $y = cx$; otherwise, they are not multiples.

Answer (score 0):

Check if either $\|x+y\|$ or $\|x-y\|$ equals $\|x\|+\|y\|$.